# how to grow sda on google compute engine?

Tags: linux, centos

I am new in gce and try to grow my /dev/sda disk.
how can I do that?
I have added 200Gb disk to my instance, then make file system on it.
this is fdisk -lu result:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 10.7 GB, 10737418240 bytes
4 heads, 32 sectors/track, 163840 cylinders, total 20971520 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0004a990

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    20969472    10483712+  83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 214.7 GB, 214748364800 bytes
86 heads, 25 sectors/track, 195083 cylinders, total 419430400 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x70f99a87

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048   419430399   209714176   83  Linux
```

But when I am running df -h, the result is:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             9.9G  998M  8.4G  11% /
tmpfs                 851M     0  851M   0% /dev/shm
```

what should I do?
Please help..
thanks..

Comment: Are you using lvms or partitions? If you don't know then can you paste a copy of your /etc/fstab via "cat /etc/fstab" or show me your logical volumes by pasting the output of the following command "sudo lvdisplay".

Comment: #
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Thu Nov 21 01:48:07 2013
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
UUID=a8cf6ab7-92fb-42c6-b95f-d437f94aaf98 / ext4    defaults,barrier=0 1 1
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0

Comment: lvdisplay resulting:   No volume groups found
(I am using persistent disks).

Comment: Unfortunately it is not as easy to expand partitions as it is with lvm. You will basically have to copy all your data from your old 10GB disk to the new 200GB disk and use the 200GB as your primary disk from now on. [This](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-can-i-use-dd-to-migrate-data-from-an-old-drive-to-a-new-drive) will get you started but you should do some research on how to extend the partition space after the copy over. I've flagged this to be moved to either unix.stackexchange or serverfault where you can get more help.

Comment: thanks. If I just add persistent disks to an instance, would my data storage limit increased? I mean I can just add disks to grow my "hosting capacity"? So I don't need to grow /dev/sda volume?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by your "hosting capacity". If all you want to do is grow the space in a specific directory then you could do that by just mounting the newly added disk to that directory.

Comment: ah.. so it is the concept.. I really messed up with my thought. could you give the code ?